# GLFW OpenGL with NuGet does not build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, nuget, glfw

The goal of my code is to display a window.

I use Visual Studio 2017 and I installed the package `nupengl.core` as well as `GLFW` and `glew`.

I can display a window but when I add this code:

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

do {
    // Clear the screen. It's not mentioned before Tutorial 02, but it can cause flickering, so it's there nonetheless.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
    glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
```

I get this error:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 opengl_nugent referenced in function_main
```

Why do I get this error message and why doesn't the glClear function work?

Comment: What files do you #include? What files do you link to?

Comment: Did you link "opengl32.lib"?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Where do I link "opengl32.lib"

Comment: @Ripi2 /*
TUTORIAL FOR OPEN GL 
*/
//including the standard libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Include GLEW. Always include before gl.h and glfw.h 
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> //handles window and keyboard
#include <glm/glm.hpp> // handles 3D

Comment: @IkechukwuAnude *"Where do I link "opengl32.lib"* - in general project Settings -> linker -> additional dependencies. Same place where you link "glew3.lib" and "glfw32.lib".

Comment: @Rabbid76 I did not link those libraries that way. I used the Nuget package manager that comes with Visual Studio.